# Why fpdi output not working in Drupal 7 but working outside of D7

Tags: drupal-7, fpdf, fpdi

I am creating a form that handles manage file type for pdf uploads. I am using [fpdi](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/). The issue is it doesn't download from the this code `$pdf->Output('D');`  Can anyone help me. Make it simple because I'm new to Drupal 7 as well.

My code is similar to this. Check their page [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/):

```
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new Fpdi();

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('Fantastic-Speaker.pdf');
$pageId = $pdf->importPage(1, PdfReader\PageBoundaries::MEDIA_BOX);

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useImportedPage($pageId, 10, 10, 90);

$pdf->Output('D');
```

Check the param 'D'. If I run that code outside of D7, it just works as expected. So maybe D7 prevents it from downloading? Please help.

Comment: I guess you are using this in a controller of D7? I'm not familiar with Drupal at all but there should be any kind of response object which needs to transfer the PDF data to the client. The `$pdf->Output('D');` call will send HTTP headers and the PDF content to the output which may be buffered by Drupal. You should use `$data = $pdf->Output('S');` and forward this to the response object.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this one by writing the file into a certain location. Then send headers() as a response and it works just fine.

```
$pdf->Output('F', '/path/to/the/file.pdf');

header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.pdf');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize('/path/to/the/file.pdf'));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile('/path/to/the/file.pdf');
```

Comment: This is nearly the same as what $pdf->Output('D'); does (without a temporary file). So the main issue seems to be somewhere else.